# creating hql query for one-to-many relationship

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have two class Domain and UserProfile . The relation between them is one to many. It is defined in UserProfile Class.I have firstName of user and domain object  I have to write hql query to retrive the UserProfile object.
I have created like this 
"from UserProfile as profile where profile.domain='"+domain+"' and  profile.firstName ='"+firstName+"' ". But it is not working.

can anyone tell me how should be the query.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_DOMAIN")
public class Domain implements Serializable {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name ="FLD_DOMAIN_ID")
  private Long domainId;

  @Column(name = "FLD_DOMAIN_NAME")
  private String domainName;
}


@Entity
@Table(name="TBL_STD_USERPROFILE")
public class UserProfile {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue
  @Column(name = "FLD_USER_ID")
  private Long userId;

  @Column(name = "FLD_First_Name")
  private FirstName firstName;

  @ManyToOne
  private Domain domain;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never use String concatenation to pass parameters to queries. Use query parameters instead (named, preferrably):

```
String hql = 
    "select u from UserProfile u"
    + " where u.firstName = :theFirstName"
    + " and u.domain = :theDomain";

return session.createQuery(hql)
              .setParameter("theFirstName", firstName)
              .setParameter("theDomain", domain)
              .list();
```

Comment: It is working, but I have one doubt ,hql queries starts with "from" keyword not "select" keyword.? am i right or wrong.? I saw hql queries starts with from .It is ok if we starts with select keyword.

Comment: You may omit the select clause, but I prefer always specifying it, to explicitely declare what is selected. In JPQL (which is the standard JPA query language, of which HQL is an implementation), the select clause is mandatory.